# Why does adding text do a div change the margin

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why adding a text do a div seems to be changing how the div is parsed by the browser? Looks like the margin-top is changed, though it isn't.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="nav-left">left</div>
  <div class="nav-logo"></div>
  <div class="nav-right">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-left, .nav-right, .nav-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}
.nav-left {
    background: red;
}
.nav-right {
    background: blue;
}
.nav-right, .nav-left {
    width: 50px;
}
.nav-logo {
    background: yellow;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Code is also here: http://jsfiddle.net/NcA8r/

Comment: Change the `vertical-align` value.. http://jsfiddle.net/4JXPb/

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but help me and others understand. Why is this needed? Why does adding text change the look? It seem to me that browser default for a div is vertical-align: baseline; , but why does the dive behave differently with text inside ?

Comment: here you can find all explained http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @Andreas Take a look at the [visual formatting model details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)

Answer (score 3):

As @JoshCrozier said, you need to add a `vertical-align` to your 3 divs.

This:

```
.nav-left, .nav-right, .nav-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Should be:

```
.nav-left, .nav-right, .nav-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align:top;
```

Comment: Yes, but why? What is the rule? ;-)

Comment: @leo because he hadn't put it there, it defaulted to vertical-align:baseline; so his text was aligned with the baseline of his 'nav' div

Comment: Thanks @shub, but I meant why `vertical-align:baseline` behaves this way. I do not understand it. ;-)

Comment: @Leo if you mean why it behaves differently with text and without, then its because the baseline is the baseline of the **text**. Without text the baseline practically becomes the baseline of the div, instead of the text. More info @ http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/ ;)

Comment: Yes, I see that, but what is the rule? I can't find the definition. Also, if I put a space there in the middle div it still does not align vertical as the other divs. But perhaps spaces inside a tag disappears, but those outside does not? Whatever outside/inside could be... ;-)

Comment: @Leo ...inline-blocks

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am beginning to accept this without a definition. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you used `display: inline-block;` in your inner divs.

inline-block elements are `vertical-align:baseline;` by default.

Check this out this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827977/css-unexpected-vertical-position-of-inline-block-elements).

> "The default value for vertical-align in CSS is baseline."

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680595/inline-block-div-elements-do-not-line-up-as-expected) too.